# Ada package & method names

Tags: ada

A question out of curiosity here, Is it possible to find the name of the method you are in ? Something like this where `Magic` should output `"foo.bar.foobar"` without resorting to a string literal.

```
with ada.text_io;
package body foo.bar is 

   function foobar return boolean is 
   begin
     ada.text_io.put_line ("I am in :" & Magic);
     return true;
   end foobar;

end foo.bar;
```

I would assume this is information is located somewhere as similar is output for stack traces, exceptions and profiling tools etc, but i cannot find it documented anywhere!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I'm sure you already know, Ada (unfortunately) doesn't support reflection.

However... if you're using GNAT and are okay with compiler-specific utilities, you can get this kind of information from the package [GNAT.Source_Info](http://www.radford.edu/~nokie/classes/320/std_lib_html/gnat-source_info.html).

Comment: Thanks Marc, Just what i was wanting :)